# Viewpager indicator along with Title name

Tags: android

I would like to have a view pager indicator adjacent to the screen name in title bar. Is this possible through any sdk api's or third party libraries?

Comment: try this [JakeWharton_Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: Jake Wharton does not provide support to viewpager to the right side of title name, as I explained in question.